# Return all Records from Table with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a program that sends a user id through AJAX and to a php program that searches a table for all records that match that user id. The problem is that it's only returning one row and I need for it to return all the rows that match. Any ideas on how to do this?

MySQL statement in php:

```
$id=$_POST["id"];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM crime_map WHERE user_id = '$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

$output[]=$row;

echo json_encode($output);
```

JS code:

```
function submitform() {

    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    var datastr = 'id=' + id;
    alert(datastr);
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: 'api.php', 
        data: datastr,      
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){

            var user_id = data[0];
            alert(user_id);
        }                                   
    })      
}
```

Comment: var user_id = data[0];  here you take one row. data[] is the array of rows. use other indexes to reach other rows, e.g. data[1]

Comment: is this code adding each row to output or replacing the first row ? $output[]=$row;

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` in a modern browser (Firefox with Firebug console, Chrome, or even IE9) and see its content?

Comment: Good suggestion, Guillaume. I am receiving all of the records from the AJAX call. Now what would I do to put them in a hash with the user_id for the key and then an array for each row? Maybe an array of arrays?

Comment: What I'm doing is trying to find the user in the table and then find all of the GPS coordinates that are stored with that user's id (there will be several rows). The table is set up like this: user id, latitude, longitude. I want to take the locations and then draw a polyline on a google map.

Comment: The data that is returned (`data`) comes back as a list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function submitform() {

    var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
    var datastr = 'id=' + id;
    //alert(datastr);
    $.ajax({    
        type: "POST",
        url: 'api.php', 
        data: datastr,      
        dataType: 'json',                   
        success: function(data){

            //var user_id = data[0];
            //alert(user_id);
            if(data.length > 0)
            {
                for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
                {
                    alert("User: " + data[i].user_id);
                    // here you have the user_id and any other fields from the table e.g. lat/long
                }
            }
        }                                   
    })      
}
```

Have a look at the Google Maps Polyline reference for how to plot the points:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline